# Json Format Error While creating

Tags: c#, json, windows

I have created a json file from a list and as of now the code is working fine. But in the code I need to check whether a file exist with the same name, if so just append the new details to the file else create a new file. Unfortunately the file is getting written in a wrong format.
Here is my code

```
 List<DeviceData> tempDate = new List<DeviceData>();
                                DeviceData D = new DeviceData();
                                D.deviceId = St_Id.ToString();
                                D.ansId = AnswerStr;

                                D.date = DateTime.Now;
                                tempDate.Add(D);
                                string ans = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tempDate, Formatting.Indented);

                                //System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"E:\" + " device.json", ans);

                                if (File.Exists(@"E:\" + " device.json"))
                                {
                                    File.AppendAllText(@"E:\" + " device.json", ans);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"E:\" + " device.json", ans);
                                }
```

The file I getting is

```
[
  {
    "deviceId": "2",
    "ansId": "2",
    "date": "2014-11-10T15:30:58.7717853+05:30"
  }
][
  {
    "deviceId": "4",
    "ansId": "1",
    "date": "2014-11-10T15:31:00.8717853+05:30"
  }
]
```

[image]

Can any one help .Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess the space in front of your filename ruins your File.Exists. Try this `File.Exists(@"E:\" + "device.json"))`

Comment: what is "wrong format"? do you mean it does not start new line?

Comment: @kennyzx Update the question with the image ..Please have a look on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format is wrong and it should be like this:

```
[
    {
        "deviceId": "2",
        "ansId": "2",
        "date": "2014-11-10T15:30:58.7717853+05:30"
    },
    {
        "deviceId": "4",
        "ansId": "1",
        "date": "2014-11-10T15:31:00.8717853+05:30"
    }
]
```

So you have to modify your code like this:

```
if (File.Exists(@"E:\" + " device.json"))
{
     ans = ans.Replace('[', ',');
     var json =  File.ReadAllText(@"E:\" + " device.json");
     json.Replace("]", ans);
     File.AppendAllText(@"E:\" + " device.json", json);
}
```

Comment: Now it is showing like    [
  {
    "deviceId": "4",
    "ansId": "2",
    "date": "2014-11-10T18:10:44.3001989+05:30"
  }
,
  {
    "deviceId": "2",
    "ansId": "2",
    "date": "2014-11-10T18:12:04.8850159+05:30"
  }
],
  {
    "deviceId": "4",
    "ansId": "1",
    "date": "2014-11-10T18:13:28.181853+05:30"
  }
]

Answer (score 0):

The Problem seems to be that you have multipley arrays in you json file.

One Solution would be to first Parse your old json to a new list, then add the new device und then overwrite the file with.

The other one would be to extract the content from the decoding with the help of a regular expression, and inserting it in the old json file (between the last "}" und the "]")